# REST API considerations for expansion in the future

Tags: java, api, rest, expansion

*First, a small disclaimer: this is my first attempt at building a REST API, so please bear with me on this one* :)

I am working on designing a REST API in Java for an Angular app, and I've come across a situation that I don't really know how to handle.
For starters, the API will only serve that one Angular app, and it will basically enable users to edit their properties, along with creating various resources linked to their respective user.

The concept I'm having trouble dealing with is allowing other apps access to the API, in the future. How would you design it to allow for that kind of expansion?

My idea is that each API call will carry an application-specific token, in the HTTP headers, which uniquely identifies that app. That would require the developer to register beforehand, and receive the token, to use in his calls. The issue with this approach is that I don't know exactly how secure it would be. Do you think this is a good starting point, or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it right. The problem with your approach is that it's pretty easy to spoof the application id, especially when it does not expire. The way it usually works, each app which accesses your service would have an `Application Key`, and `Application Secret`. You use `app key` to identify the app and `secret` to either authenticate with the service and obtain access token or to include a signature with each request which would be encrypted with app secret as a key.
So here is the suggested workflow:

- Client application authenticates with the service using `app ke`y and `app secret`
- Service returns `access token` - something to identify a working session
- Client app will include `access token` with each request to the service hence establishing an identity of client
- `Access token` should expire
- The service should only work through TLS since application secret is sent as clear text during authentication call.

This is inspired by the way [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/) does things, minus the idea that client app might want to access users on your service (Like you can use third-party app to access user's data on Facebook). If you do have a concept of users, you might want to go with OAuth2, here is a good tutorial on it: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified
You also might want to take a look how others secure their REST services. Here is AWS, for exapmle:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that clears things up for me. I want to have a clear perspective about the entire authentication process long before I start designing/writing anything.

Comment: There are quite a few risks involved in doing your own authentication design. See http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/api-authentication-considerations-and.html for a discussion on this issue.

Comment: Indeed. I've been looking into OAuth 2 as a means to secure the API. Seems widely accepted by the industry, and that's a very important aspect.